# ActionController::ParameterMissingはどうすれば改善されるのか？？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

皆様、質問がございます、よろしくお願い申し上げます。
googleで問題解決を試みましたが、出来なかったため質問致します。

質問
strongparamaterをprivateメソッド以下に定義しているのですが、定義している値は存在しないとerrorが生じるため、ご指導頂ければと思います。
関連するファイルが足りない場合は合わせてご指導頂ければと思います。

[image: 問題のキャプチャ]

関連するファイル

PinsController.rb

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @pin = Pin.new
  end

  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:name,:title, :description)
  end
 end
```

routes.rb

```
 PinBoard::Application.routes.draw do
 resources :pins
 root 'pins#index'

 end
```

Comment: 見たところ、Viewに問題があるためパラメータが正しく渡されていないようです。Viewのコード（特にform全体）を追記してください。

Comment: エラー画面を見ると単に title や description を渡していますね。
これは 「pinのtitle」 や 「pinのdescription」 のように渡さないと行けないと思います。
いづれにせよ上述のコメントで指摘があるように、 view のコードを載せれば回答が得られると思います。

あと、タグは「ruby」のみですが、「ruby on rails」のタグを付けるべきだと思います。